# alternative to wkhtmltopdf to render pdf with javascript charts and bootstrap classes

Tags: javascript, python, django, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I have a web application and I use the tool wkhtmltopdf to perform pdf exports. I am using wkhtmltopdf version 0.12.4 with **unpatched** QT (minimal version). 
I want to add a footer to the pdf pages and I saw that the wkhtmltopdf version with patched QT support this operation with the flag `--footer-html`.

Unfortunately I noticed that the css and js engine under this version create some problem in rendering my html pages:

- First of all there are problem with the grid system in Bootstrap v >
  4.1
- Then also the javascript chart in my page are no more rendered in the
  pdf with this version of wkhtmltopdf

So, is there an alternative to wkhtmltopdf that allow me to export to pdf my web pages ? 
My project is written in django / javascript so I would prefer a python of javascript tool.

I also tried *pdfkit* but I discart it because I saw it is based on wkhtmltopdf , and *django-weasyprint* but I discarted because it does not support javascript (so my charts are not rendered).

Finally the tool should allow me to connect to the web page passing **cookies** or similar, because login is required to access the pages.

### Another solution I thought is the following:

Create the pdf with the version of wkhtmltopdf that correctly render my pdf (i.e. 0.12.4 without QT) and then edit the pdf with another tool and add the footer .

Is there a tool that allow me to do this operation ??

Thanks to all